# disable wpautop on multiple custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out the best way to disable wpautop in 4 custom post types.

I am using this snippet:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wp1_remove_autop_for_posttype', 0 );

    function wp1_remove_autop_for_posttype( $content )
{

'esh' === get_post_type() && remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
return $content;
}
```

I also need to remove it for custom post types named menu, op, external. do i just copy and paste this and change the function name or is there a cleaner way to do it?

wisdom appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make array with all `CPT` that you need to remove `wpautop` from, and then in this hook to do:

```
$cpts = ['esh', 'menu', 'op', 'external'];
if ( in_array( get_post_type(), $cpts ) ) { 
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
```

You can check this function [get_post_types()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types), if you want to grab `CPTs` automatically. For instance, if you want to loop through all your `CPTs`:

```
$cpts = get_post_types(['_builtin' => false, 'public' => true], 'names');
```

or of course, you can put other arguments to select needed types that you want to loop through.